# Trying unsuccessfully to create a voting bot using scapy

Tags: python, bots, wireshark, scapy, packet

***Summarizing the problem:***

> I'm trying to create a voting bot using scapy but when I send the
>   post packet of the vote it doesn't do anything

I want to improve my scapy skills and to do so I decided to build a voting bot. In order to do so I did the following steps :

1. Find a website that contains some vote options.
2. Vote normally (without scapy) and on the way sniffing the packets with wireshark and scrapy
3. Find the "http post" packet and send it again.

Unfortunately this didn't work me. I did so and find successfully the "http post" packet but when I sent it again I didn't receive any response from the server ( unlike when I did it by using google chrome like every user, where after sniffing I could do "following tcp stream" in wireshark and see more packets )

Can someone suggest why this is happening?

Comment: if you are struggling to find the correct packets, try "postman" for requests, it is a program that lets you test everything out without any code, just enter the link and the load

Comment: Are you literally just re-sending one sniffed packet from a previous TCP session? Because, if so, that packet will just get dropped by the server. You would need to set up a new TCP session and send the data from the previous session in the new one. `scapy` is a good tool for sniffing the data, but to re-send it, it is much simpler to use something else like Python's built-in `socket` module to set up the TCP session and send the data.

Comment: @KyleWillmon I do something like - packets = sniff(10)

Comment: sendp(packets[3])

Comment: when packets[3] is the correct packet

Comment: he dropping it automaticly?

Comment: Right. That won't work because you are bypassing the TCP handshake and sending a packet with no context. TCP is designed to detect and drop packets that are accidentally delivered twice. You are deliberately delivering a packet twice and TCP will detect and drop it.